# Is there any API like `llvm::InitializeX86Targets()` only for X86 target machine in LLVM?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

In LLVM tutorial https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl08.html#choosing-a-target, it use:

```
InitializeAllTargetInfos();
InitializeAllTargets();
InitializeAllTargetMCs();
InitializeAllAsmParsers();
InitializeAllAsmPrinters();
```

to initialize all targets/asmparsers/asmprinters.

Is there any API like `llvm::InitializeX86Target()` to initialize only X86 target machine ?